# Mostrar y ocultar las opciones de mi select segun la anterior con AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

les presento mi problema:
Tengo un formulario dinamico, este tiene pues varios campos y entre ellos tengo un select que tiene las opciones: capitulo, subcapitulo, nivel 1, nivel 2, nivel 3 y nivel 4, cada vez que selecciono una opcion de este select se crea un nuevo formulario abajo del anterior que es exactamente igual y asi sucesivamente. 

Lo que ocupo es que al seleccionar una opcion de mi select y se cree otro formulario, que en este siguiente formulario vengan unicamente ciertas opciones que ciertas opciones basandose en la anterior ya seleccionado, por ejemplo: que al seleccionar Capitulo en el siguiente select solo te de de opciones Subcapitulo y Nivel 1, luego si seleccionas Nivel 2 solo te de de opcion seleccionar Nivel 3.

Les adjunto el codigo que llevo, *TODO ESTO SOLO CON ANGULARJS*

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []); 
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];

$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
$scope.choices.push({id:'choice'+newItemNo});
};

$scope.removeChoice = function(index) {   
$scope.choices.splice(index, 1);
};

var initialOptions = ['Capitulo', 'Subcapitulo', 'Nivel 1', 'Nivel 2',     'Nivel 3', 'Nivel 4'];
$scope.options = initialOptions;
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[0];



}]);
```

---

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<fieldset class="form-group"  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
<form name="myForm">
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="o for o in options" > ng-change="addNewChoice()">
</select>

 <input type="number" ng-model="choice.clave" name="" placeholder="Ingresa > la clave">

      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.concepto" name="" placeholder="Ingresa el concepto">

      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.unidad" name="" placeholder="Ingresa la unidad" min="0">

      <input type="number" ng-model="choice.cantidad" name="" placeholder="Ingresa la cantidad" min="0">

      <input type="number" ng-model="choice.punitario" name="" placeholder="Precio unitario" min="0" ng-click="showme=true">

<input type="number" ng-model="choice.importe" name="" placeholder="Importe">

<button class="remove btn btn-danger" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">Eliminar</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
<button class="addfields btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Agregar</button>


</div>
```